# How can I use multiple WHERE statements when using IN with array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
function av_connections_search($string){
    global $wpdb;
    // remove url parameter from string
    $string = trim($string,'s=');
    $search = explode('%20',$string);
    // query the wp_connections database table according to search entry
    $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}connections
        WHERE contact_first_name IN (".implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($search), '%s')).")
      ";
    // prepare() to prevent sql injection
    $query = call_user_func_array(array($wpdb, 'prepare'), array_merge(array($sql), $search));
    // get query results
    //var_dump($query);
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    // return if no results
    if(empty($results)){
        return false;
    }
    // flush $wpdb cache
    $wpdb->flush();
    // return data to search.php
    return $results;
}
```

where `$string` looks like ?s=search+these+terms when passed to the function

My question, how can I use multiple WHERE statements? I've tried simply:

```
WHERE contact_first_name IN (".implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($search), '%s')).")
OR contact_last_name IN (".implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($search), '%s')).")
```

but it fails completely. When I do:

```
WHERE contact_first_name OR contact_last_name IN (".implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($search), '%s')).")
```

it only returns `contact_last_name`. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Ok, so I'm quite sure the problem lies within this:

`$query = call_user_func_array(array($wpdb, 'prepare'), array_merge(array($sql), $search));`

but, for a lack of sleep I cannot wrap my mind around why it's not merging the array with both WHERE clauses.

**EDIT 2** Should this not work? It works great if I use the single WHERE clause, but the moment I use OR and another clause, it returns nothing, which makes no sense because this is the query:

`SELECT * FROM wp_connections WHERE`contact_first_name`IN (%s, %s) OR`contact_last_name`IN (%s, %s) " [1]=> string(4) "Mina" [2]=> string(5) "Morse"`

**EDIT 3** I do not believe prepare() is the problem. Consider this (doesn't work):

```
global $wpdb;
$string = trim($string,'s=');
$search = explode('%20',$string);
$how_many = count($search);
$placeholders = array_fill(0, $how_many, '%s');

$format = implode(', ', $placeholders);

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_connections WHERE contact_first_name IN($format) OR contact_last_name IN($format)";

$results = $wpdb->query($query, $search);
return $results;
```

Even removing prepare completely, same result. What am I missing? If I remove the `OR` condition and just check one value, it works fine, but OR kills the query.

**EDIT 4** It turns out this was the solution:

```
$results = $wpdb->query($query, $search, $search);
```

I was missing the second $search variable... *scratching head still

Comment: just echo `implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($search), '%s'))` are u getting the correct words...????

Comment: That prints `%s, %s, %s`

Comment: then how it searches the right way....

Comment: Try this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: With this `$query = call_user_func_array(array($wpdb, 'prepare'), array_merge(array($sql), $search));` which returns `SELECT * FROM wp_connections WHERE contact_first_name IN ('mina', 'john', 'paul')`

Comment: Try putting that query in the mysql query builder and execute...

Comment: Prepare is not expected to work with "IN" clauses, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: So, why does it work with one condition then? I don't see where prepare() isn't meant to be used with IN. Also, both those links are the same.

Comment: I've found a solution... still trying to wrap my head around the problem though. I'll post it shortly.

Comment: For the record, I ended up ditching this method for a FULLTEXT search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
WHERE contact_first_name IN (".implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($search), '%s')).") OR contact_last_name IN (".implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($search), '%s')).")
```

**UPDATE**

The correct answer to this question is **The query is correct, it's the dynamic parameters that are wrong which cause the query syntax to become wrong.** It was actually in the comments section right under this answer, so merged it with the accepted answers!

Comment: The query is correct, may be it's the dynamic parameters that are wrong which causes the query syntax to become wrong.

Comment: Idk, I'm stumped. 
`var_dump(array_merge(array($sql), $search));` 
gives:
`array(4) { [0]=> string(150) " SELECT * FROM wp_connections WHERE contact_first_name IN (%s, %s, %s) OR contact_last_name IN (%s, %s, %s) " [1]=> string(4) "mina" [2]=> string(4) "john" [3]=> string(5) "morse" }`

Comment: Can you print the _$sql_ and see what the actual query is that is being fired?

Comment: That's it right above. The %s are replaced with "mina", "john", etc.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer @Gurminder Singh because your comment above is actually correct. It was a parameter issue after all.